# Generate Auto-Number with considering Threading & Concurrent Request

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, multithreading, transactions

So I need to create a feature for generating auto number with +1 increment for each transaction that is saved. So basic requirement is this auto number generated must not be duplicated.

Table being used is

```
AutoNumber    |    TransactionInv
----------    |    ----------------
Id            |    Id
Code          |    TransactionNo
LastNumber    |
```

Example record of table is

```
AutoNumber

Id   |   Code   |   LastNumber
1    | AN-INV   |   17  
1    | AN-PO    |   20

TransactionInv

Id   | TransactionNo
1    | 2017-00017
2    | 2017-00018
```

Current function that I create

```
public string GetAutoNo(string code, IRepository<AutoNumber, Guid> autoNumberRepository, IUnitOfWorkManager uow)
    {
        using (var scope = uow.Begin(new UnitOfWorkOptions() { Scope = TransactionScopeOption.Required, IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted }))
        {
            var autoNumber = autoNumberRepository.Where(c => c.Id == Id && c.Code == code).OrderByDescending(c => c.LastNumber).FirstOrDefault();
            if (autoNumber == null)
            {
                autoNumber = new AutoNumber();
                autoNumber.Code = code;
                autoNumber.LastNumber = 0;
            }
            double currentNumber = autoNumber.LastNumber + 1;
            var isUsed = autoNumberRepository.FirstOrDefault(c => c.LastNumber == currentNumber);
            if (isUsed == null)
            {
                autoNumber.LastNumber += 1;
                autoNumberRepository.Insert(autoNumber);

                scope.Complete();
                return currentNumber.ToString("00000");
            }
            else
            {
                return GetAutoNo(code, autoNumberRepository, uow);
            }
        }
    }
```

My current problem is when multi user saving the transaction in a milliseconds different then it will be duplicated. Things to be take note that will auto number duplicate :

- transaction save processing time
- user connection speed when save transaction
- many user saving at the same time / many users accessing transaction table

There are solution that I haven't tried yet, which is holdlock / tablelock, but if I have many users I think this solution is not a good idea, that's why I still think whether any better idea for this ?

If you guys have a experience in doing the same thing, maybe can advice me the better approach for this function ? I really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: if the application is ment to run as a single instance and not to be distributed or load balanced, then you can use a lock inside the method to ensure that only one request is executed at a time. This will affect the thorughput but will comply with your described requirements. To cope with the throughput, you can also cache the last number in the object to not need to fetch it everytime. But as I said, this only works if there is to be only one instance of this application running this code.

Comment: @Cyrus thanks for the explanation, yeah I also think the last resort is to use the lock. I wonder how some big ERP brand is handling the Auto Numbering when the concurrent user is saving transaction at a split second different :D  .

Comment: I think they most probably offload this task to the database, which handle this very well. You should consider that. Or they use GUID and just have a timestamp (on db level) of when the transaction was committed to be able to see the order. Handling unique incremental numbers in your own application is something you should always avoid and instead harness the power of the database which is equipped for that. Handling this in the application is complex, error prone, limiting and does not scale well.

Comment: This should be handled in the procedure in your DB. Your app should simply send the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to consider using Sequence Number, then use NEXT VALUE every time it is called.

By doing this you can avoid duplicate numbers.